# Hiding plain text password with sqlplus command line

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I wish to use a sqlplus command with password hidden from view such that it doesn't show up on ps -ef command.

I know there are a lot of solutions provided all over internet blogs but most of them seem to require admin privileges and I have restricted access on this server. And rest of them just don't seem to work me.

The command that I am currently using is as below:

```
sqlplus -s SOME_USERNAME/SOME_PASSWORD@somedns.intra.com:1500/SOMESID @some.sql
```

Legend:

SOME_USERNAME: schema/user

SOME_PASSWORD: password

SOMESID: SID for this DB.

@some.sql: An sql file containing insert statements.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Update: Forgot to mention that this sqlplus command will be used inside a shell script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I input the password from within a shell script in this case?

You can use [a heredoc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<!EOF
connect SOME_USERNAME/SOME_PASSWORD@somedns.intra.com:1500/SOMESID
@some.sql
!EOF
```

The `connect` and `@some.sql` are treated as an input stream to SQL*Plus, as if you'd typed them in an interactive session, and are not part of the initial call to the executable - so the connection details don't appear in `ps` output.

You can also use variables if you want to, incidentally, as the variable expansion happens in the shell before it passes the stream to the executable - so even though SQL*Plus wouldn't understand say `$PASSWD`, referring to that in the heredoc works and the actual variable value is passed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Only first solution worked for me. (the one with connect) The second one failed as below:

{{ Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied

SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus }}

But thank you very much for the first solution. I am going to use that. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure there is a way to do that - though using echo for stdin doesn't work either - but it escapes me at the moment. As the first one works for you, I won't worry about it too much...

Answer (score 3):

- Use `sqlplus -s SOME_USERNAME@\"somedns.intra.com:1500/SOMESID\" @some.sql` and enter your password on the command line.
- Or use external authentication and don't use a password at all
- Finally, SOMESID is not a SID, it's a Service Name.  The Easy Connect syntax you use only works with service names.  SIDs are very very old-school.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this sqlplus command will be executed within a shell script. Let me update the main question.

Comment: How do I input the password from within a shell script in this case?