# how to connect oracle database from unix without showing password

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

i am trying to connect Oracle database from Linux server where environment variables and tnsnames.ora cannot be modified.

I am using following code to connect which is working fine and i am able to connect database using sqlplus.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl
export PATH=/opt/oracle/product/112030_cl_64/cl/bin:$PATH
sqlplus myuser/mypass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(Host=x)(Port=x)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=x)))
```

Now i am not able to find any solution how can i execute it so that i don't need to execute it manually every time and i don't want to share the password with anyone else. i want to connect db using sqlplus from a shell script to spool data.

any lead would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Maybe this?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-803496D2-19C7-4F02-94EC-C13EDD8FB17B)

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'showing' - are you concerned about someone else being able to see the password in your script (which you should be, however much you try to lock down privs), or only about anyone being able to [see it via `ps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776720/266304)?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to use Oracle Wallet to store database passwords and so that your scripts can use them.
Otherwise if you can login as the oracle product owner ("oracle" most of the time) and it belong to the "dba" group you can connect as sys without typing the password (sqlplus / as sysdba) but it's privileged access, don't use it for business processes.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the password; you'll be prompted to enter it, but it'll be invisible (Windows example, but doesn't matter in this case):

```
M:\>sqlplus scott@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on ╚et Tra 11 13:01:35 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

That, of course, requires you to *type* it every time. If it is stored, somewhere, anyone else could see it. Perhaps there is a way, but I don't know it.